# excel formula problem

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Kindly check the below written formula, if the formula is not correct then please provide me  the correct one that is related to this.

```
IF(A1:AV7000=F1,vlookup(f2,B1:C7000,2,0),0)
```

As I have tried above written formulas, but it's not working.

Comment: The formula is not correct. It should be `IF(A1=42;1;0)`. Seriously, how would we know?

Comment: The three basic things for any such report are (1) what you did, (2) what you got, and (3) what you expected.  I can see what you did.  I don't know what you mean by "not working", so I don't know what you got.  You haven't provided any clue of what you expected, or what you want.

Comment: +1 for David Thornley's comment. Provide us with the three things he outlined, and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a range of cells like `A1:AV7000` directly to a single cell like `F1`. I suspect that you probably want to combine a `VLOOKUP` on the first range with the `ISNA` function, perhaps?

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F1,A1:AV7000,1,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(F2,B1:C7000,2,FALSE))
```

As written, however, this formula is nonsense. You are looking for the value in cell `F1` but the range `A1:AV7000` contains `F1` so the `VLOOKUP` is always going to succeed

Answer (score 0):

This question may already have been solved, but, VLOOKUP's are rather slow on large data sets; MATCH is usually a faster way to go