# Problem with Excel worksheet function always defaulting to the false conditional

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Can somebody figure out what is wrong with my Excel formula?

```
 =IF(vdnh.rpt!$B:$B=B$1,VLOOKUP($A3,vdnh.rpt!$A$21:$L$34,6),"-")
```

It is not working and it keeps giving me "-" answer.

Comment: It's wrong that you don't provide details to us. Check this > [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [excel formula problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598471/excel-formula-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't ask for the range to equal one cell, unless maybe you try an array formula.  Just go the cell that formula is in, and then hit CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, and see if it works then.

Comment: Do you know what function I should use?

Comment: Not intirely true: if the formula is in a cell in row 1 then `vdnh.rpt!$B:$B=B$1` returns a result based on `vdnh.rpt!$B1` by `implicit intersection`.  An implicit intersection occurs when Excel chooses a value from a multicell range based on the row or column of the formula that contains the reference.   But can't tell from the question if this is the intended behaviour or not!

Comment: @user778936, if you gave more information on what you wanted the formula to give you, I could figure things out much more exactly.

Comment: @Chris, I agree, I'm not exactly describing what is going on behind the scenes, just trying to help him understand where his problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`vdnh.rpt!$B:$B=B$1` is false (the value in B1 does not match the value of the cell that is in column B in the same row as the formula) so the false part of your IF statement `"-"` is being shown.